# Dynamically creating object based on type

Tags: c#, reflection, autofac

I have the following code:

```
public async Task DispatchAsync(NoticeChannelType type, string message)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case NoticeChannelType.Email:
                {
                    var email = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NoticeEmail>(message);
                    await _channelResolver.ResolveAsync(email);
                }
                break;
            case NoticeChannelType.Pushover:
                {
                    var pushover = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NoticePushover>(message);
                    await _channelResolver.ResolveAsync(pushover);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

I would like to remove this switch somehow, create and cast the object to the concrete type.

After that the `channelResolver.ResolveAsync` is implemented as follows:

```
public async Task ResolveAsync<T>(T channel) where T : INoticeChannel
    {
        if (channel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(channel),
                $"Channel: '{typeof(T).Name}' cannot be null.");

        var handler = _context.Resolve<INoticeExecutor<T>>();

        await handler.SendAsync(channel);
    }
```

I was trying to refactor it to something like this:

```
public async Task DispatchAsync(NoticeChannelType type, string message)
    {
        var channel = _context.ResolveKeyed<INoticeChannel>(type);

        Type myType = Type.GetType(channel.GetType().FullName);

        await _channelResolver.ResolveAsync((INoticeChannel)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, myType));
    }
```

but after that in the `channelResolver.ResolveAsync` type `T` is `INoticeChannel` and not the concrete type so the `_context.Resolve<INoticeExecutor<T>>();` can`t resolve it.

Is this possible to remove this switch and make this code more elegant and easier to maintain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the `ResolveAsync` generic method using either reflection or [DLR Dynamic Dispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052(v=vs.110).aspx), although I'm not sure it would make the code more elegant (the former is ugly like any reflection code) and easier to maintain (with both techniques you lose the compile time type safety).

But here you go:

*Reflection:*

```
public async Task DispatchAsync(NoticeChannelType type, string message)
{
    var channelType = _context.ResolveKeyed<INoticeChannel>(type).GetType();
    var channel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, channelType);
    var resolveMethod = _channelResolver.GetType().GetMethod("ResolveAsync")
        .MakeGenericMethod(channelType);
    await (Task)resolveMethod.Invoke(_channelResolver, new object[] { channel });
}
```

(if `ResolveAsync` is interface method, replace `_channelResolver.GetType()` with `typeof(IChannelResolver)` where `IChannelResolver` is your interface name)

*DLR Dynamic Dispatch:*

```
public async Task DispatchAsync(NoticeChannelType type, string message)
{
    var channelType = _context.ResolveKeyed<INoticeChannel>(type).GetType();
    var channel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, channelType);
    await (Task)_channelResolver.ResolveAsync((dynamic)channel);
}
```

Comment: Big thanks, I know that we can't have everything (elegant, easy to maintain etc.) but I hope I can deal with it in this scenario.